# Adding tabs to non delimited text file with empty and variable length columns

Tags: parsing, powershell

I have a non-delimited text file and want to parse it to add tabs at specific spots to delimit columns. The columns are sometimes empty or vary in length, which is why I need to add tabs to those specific spots.  I had found the answer to this once a couple of years ago on the net using batch, but now can't find it or the code.  I already have the following code to replace more than 2 spaces in the file, but this doesn't account for when the columns are empty.

```
gc $FileToOpen | % { $_ -replace '  +',"`t" } | set-content $FileToSave
```

So, I need to read each line, but be able to only read a portion (certain number of characters) of it and add the tabs after each portion to itself.

Here is a sample of the data file, the top row is the header and the data rows have no blank lines in between them:

```
MRUN    Number      Name                X  Exception Reason   Data                          CDM# Quantity              D.O.S
000000  00000000    Name                W  MODIFIER CANNOT BE FILED WITHOUT  08/13/2015                                          0000000   0                     08/13/2015
000000  00000000    Name                W  MODIFIER CANNOT BE FILED WITHOUT                                                      0000000   0                     08/13/2015
```

The second data row is missing Data.

Using Ansgar's answer, my code that does find empty fields:

```
gc $FileToOpen |
  ? { $_ -match '^(.{8})(.{12})(.{20})(.{3})(.{34})(.{62})(.{10})(.{22})(.{10})$' } |
  % { "{0}`t{1}`t{2}`t{3}`t{4}`t{5}`t{6}`t{7}`t{8}" -f $matches[1].Trim(), $matches[2].Trim(), $matches[3].Trim(), $matches[4].Trim(), $matches[5].Trim(), $matches[6].Trim(), $matches[7].Trim(), $matches[8].Trim(), $matches[9].Trim() } |
  Set-Content $FileToSave
```

Thanks for your patience Ansgar, I know I tried it!  I really do appreciate the help!

Comment: You're right Ansgar, though I was more looking for ideas (assistance) than expect someone to write the code for me.

Comment: The file's columns always start at specific locations on each line, if the column is empty only spaces fill to the next columns start. The columns are not the same width, but always have at least 2 spaces between each column.

Comment: The sum of the character counts in your regular expression is 181. Your sample input is only 130 characters wide. Please provide valid sample input *and* the output you're getting from it. Make sure both samples are indented by exactly 4 spaces, so they're correctly formatted. You may obfuscate sensitive data, but make sure not to change the length of the lines. 2 or 3 lines are sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, the script does indeed deal with blanks.  The problem was on my end, as I import the file into excel and excel was treating consecutive delimiters as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to have an input file with fixed-width columns, you should probably use a regular expression for transforming the input into a tab-delimited format.

Assume the following input file:

```
A     B   C   
foo   13  22  
bar   4   17  
baz   142 23
```

The file has 3 columns. The first column is 6 characters wide, the other two columns 4 characters each.

The transformation could be done with a regular expression like this:

```
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt' |
  ? { $_ -match '^(.{6})(.{4})(.{4})$' } |
  % { "{0}`t{1}`t{2}" -f $matches[1].Trim(), $matches[2].Trim(), $matches[3].Trim() } |
  Set-Content 'C:\path\to\output.txt'
```

The regular expression defines the columns by character count and captures them in groups (parentheses). The groups can then be accessed as the indexes 1 and above of the resulting `$matches` collection. Trimming removes the leading/trailing whitespace. The [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) (`-f`) then inserts the trimmed values into the tab-separated format string.

If the last column has a variable width (because its values are aligned to the left and don't have trailing spaces) you may need to change the regular expression to `^(.{6})(.{4})(.{,4})$` to take care of that. The quantifier `{,4}` (or `{0,4}`) means up to four times the preceding expression.

Comment: This looks awesome!  What is happening on the % line, what's with the two tabs?

Comment: @LawrenceKnowlton `%` is an alias for [`ForEach-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849731.aspx), which is used to loop over the elements from a pipeline. ``{0}`t{1}`t{2}`` is a format string for the [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) (`-f`).

Comment: Ok, I'm still not sure why you have two tabs in the format string. The link didn't discuss that for the format operator. It makes me think that there will be a tab in front and back of each element in the match array.

Comment: @LawrenceKnowlton The file is processed line-by-line, so the format string is for an entire row. My sample input file has 3 columns of fixed width. The output file is supposed to have these columns delimited by tabs. 3 columns means 2 delimiting tabs. For n columns you need n-1 tabs.

Comment: Ahh, I zee!  Brilliant!  Thank you for explaining that!

Comment: Well, now that I've had time to implement this, it does not put a tab if a data field has a blank.  This is occurring, because the trim command kills the blank field it before a tab can be put in its proper location.  So, I'm basically back at ground zero.  Love the concept, just needs a tweak.

Comment: I tried removing the trim commands, but it still misses the blank fields.

Comment: @LawrenceKnowlton The code works just fine with my sample input, even if I make some of the fields blank, so the issue is either with your adaptation of my code or with your input data. Please provide evidence.

Comment: I only added my column widths, more tabs and matches to the script.

Comment: Ok, I've added it to the bottom of my question.  To show you the output I'd have to do a screenshot which contains patient info, can't do that.  The sample of my data rows are an accurate copy and paste from the data file.  The header row is off but that's inconsequential.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87311/discussion-between-lawrence-knowlton-and-ansgar-wiechers).